# I'm getting the following error: view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returns None instead

Tags: python, django

After submitting my form i'm getting the following error:

`The view papa.views.record_case didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

I've tried the following solutions [view didn't return a response object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657955/view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-none-instead) and [the solution explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810931/django-test-valueerror-the-view-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-return) but not always resolved.

Here is my view.py code:

```
def record_case(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        form=EnfantForm()
        context={
            "form":form,
        }
        return render(request,"papa/enfant.html",context)
    elif request.method=="POST":
        form=EnfantForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('papa:record_case'))
```

Here is my model.py file:

```
SEXE_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'M'),
    (1, 'F'),
)

class Maladie(models.Model):
    nom=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom


class Traitement(models.Model):
    code=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=25,verbose_name="Code du traitement")
    nom=models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Nom du traitement")
    maladie=models.ForeignKey(Maladie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age=models.ForeignKey("Age",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code


class Age(models.Model):
    tranche=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tranche

class Enfant(models.Model):
    sexe=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=SEXE_CHOICES)
    poid=models.FloatField()
    age=models.ForeignKey(Age,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    maladie=models.ManyToManyField(Maladie)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.sexe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at your view (`record_case`). There are three paths here:

a. An HTTP GET

b. An HTTP POST with a valid form

c. An HTTP POST with an invalid form.

In the third case, you don't return anything so `None` is returned. That's why you get the error. To fix this, you need to return again the form with the passed data, something like this:

```
def record_case(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        form=EnfantForm()
        context={
            "form":form,
        }
        return render(request,"papa/enfant.html",context)
    elif request.method=="POST":
        form=EnfantForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('papa:record_case'))
        else:
            # POST with an invalid form
            return render(request,"papa/enfant.html", {'form': form})
```